# which data structure in java can hold hashmaps as its elements?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
public static HashMap<String,Integer> users1 = new HashMap<>();
public static HashMap<String,Integer> users2 = new HashMap<>();
public static HashMap<String,Integer> users3 = new HashMap<>();
public static HashMap<String,Integer> users4 = new HashMap<>();
// Enter code here.
```

I need to add them into a arrayList or set or something and then they should be called when using that data structures index. Like is there any way to solve it

Comment: Are you facing any problem when you are adding it to ArrayList? Could you [edit] your question and include description of that problem?

Comment: Have you tried adding them to a Collection?

Comment: yeah iam not able to add them to arraylist when i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just simply use an array:

```
public static HashMap<String,Integer>[] users = HashMap<>[4];
users[0] = = new HashMap<>();
users[1] = = new HashMap<>();
users[2] = = new HashMap<>();
users[3] = = new HashMap<>();
```

And then use them:

```
users[0].add( "String", 123 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you could as simply as :

```
List<HashMap<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

// And then add them to list
list.add(users1);
list.add(users2);
...
```